# where to specify iOS version supported by my app

Tags: ios, deployment, device, target

I'm about to submit my app to appstore, and I wonder where I specify the minimum version the my app could in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your target summary, there is a dropdown for selecting "Deployment Target" set this to the lowest iOS version you wish to support.

To get to target summary, in the project navigator pane, click on your project icon (at the very top).  Then in the left pane click on the app target, and then at the top make sure the "Summary" tab is selected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `Deployment Target` should be the minimum iOS Version you want to support.

[image]

This is how you specify what OS versions you want to support. As seen here, Im supporting `4.0+`

Comment: Base SDK is not the "latest version" that your app will support, it is just the version of the SDK you are using to build the app.

Comment: so I there such thing as max supported verso, or it's only lowest version.

Comment: No such thing as a max supported version, or every app in the app store would break every time a new version of iOS came out.